# How to get the binding that a particular WCF service is using

Tags: c#, wcf, wcf-binding

Is there a way to get the binding that a WCF service is using from the object instance of the service class itself?

I'm currently debugging a WCF service and have changed the client bindings and want to see if they are the one's that are being applied to the proxy class that represents the service interface.

As an aside the proxy class is being created using the `ChannelFactory<IMyWCFService>.CreateChannel()` method. However as this is a MVC web application and the method call is done via Dependency Injection. So the proxy object is injected into my code.

So just to be clear at the point in the code where I am using the proxy object I don't have access to original ChannelFactory. I know the binding that the ChannelFactory is using as it is set whilst configuring the dependency injection container within the Global.asax.cs class. However as we are using dependency injection there is no guarantee that the ChannelFactory or indeed binding defined in the Global.asax.cs is the one being used to create the proxy object as it might have been changed by some other code. The issue I am having is we are changing explicitly setting values on the binding used in the Global.asax.cs class but this settings aren't taking affect which makes suspicous that another binding is being used.

Comment: Ususally binding specified in client config(web.config in case of MVC)

Comment: @Uriil yeah I know, I was just wondering if the service proxy object had some reference to the binding. So that you check which binding was being used.

Answer (score 4):

You can get binding from Endpoint object of service:

```
var service = new Service1Client();
Binding binding = service.Endpoint.Binding;
Console.WriteLine(binding);
```

Comment: This will work, but `Endpoint.Binding` needs to be called on the `ChannelFactory<T>`, as that is what OP is using to create the proxy.  So, for example, `ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService> factory = new ChannelFactory<IMyWcfService>()`, and then `string binding = factory.Endpoint.Binding.Name`, which will give the binding being used.

Comment: Thanks guys the info is useful but doesn't help me in this situation as I am unable to be sure how the proxy object is created - as it done for me via dependecy injection and therefore don't have access to the binding in the way that's being suggested.